# Why does CoffeeScript requires parenthesis in the following cases?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm a CoffeeScript beginner.

This is an output from: http://js2coffee.org/

**.js:**

```
var prevPost = Posts.findOne({position: this.position - 1});
```

**.coffee:**

```
prevPost = Posts.findOne(position: @position - 1)
```

**.js:**

```
Posts = new Meteor.Collection('posts');
```

**.coffee:**

```
@Posts = new Meteor.Collection("posts")
```

And why not parenthesis here?

**.js:**

```
Posts.update(nextPost._id, {$set: {position: nextPost.position - 1}});
```

**.coffee:**

```
Posts.update nextPost._id,
    $set:
      position: nextPost.position - 1
```

Comment: My wild guess (also a newbie to coffeejs) is that it has to do with the number and/or type of arguments. Notice how in your first two cases you only have one argument, and in the second you have two, one of which is an object? What you are doing with the return of the method seems to matter too. `var foo = foo.bar(...` vs `foo.bar(...`

Comment: Is your question about j2coffee or about CoffeeScript?

Comment: @Michael_Scharf CoffeeScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Language

The [Coffeescript documentation](http://coffeescript.org/#language) gives a good insight regarding this issue:

> You **don't need to use parentheses** to invoke a function **if you're passing arguments**. The implicit call wraps forward to the end of the line or block expression.

`console.log sys.inspect object` → `console.log(sys.inspect(object));`

## Style

From [polarmobile/coffeescript-style-guide](https://github.com/polarmobile/coffeescript-style-guide#functions) you can see more definition about why and when to use parenthesis:

> When calling functions, choose to **omit or include parentheses in such a way that optimizes for readability**. Keeping in mind that "readability" can be subjective, the following examples demonstrate cases where parentheses have been omitted or included in a manner that the community deems to be optimal:

```
baz 12

brush.ellipse x: 10, y: 20 # Braces can also be omitted or included for readability

foo(4).bar(8)

obj.value(10, 20) / obj.value(20, 10)

print inspect value

new Tag(new Value(a, b), new Arg(c))
```

## Questions

**Q:** Why does CoffeeScript requires parenthesis in the following cases?

**A:** It doesn't

**Q:** And why not parenthesis here?

**A:** Like parameters **line breaks** are another way to improve readability, in the example you provided since there is some complexity in the arguments the `js2coffee` is wise enough to suggest the use of line breaks.

You can [test this](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aPosts.update%20nextPost._id%2C%0A%20%20%24set%3A%0A%20%20%20%20position%3A%20nextPost.position%20-%201%0A%0APosts.update%28nextPost._id%2C%0A%20%20%24set%3A%0A%20%20%20%20position%3A%20nextPost.position%20-%201%0A%29%0A%0APosts.update%28nextPost._id%2C%20%24set%3A%20position%3A%20nextPost.position%20-%201%29%0A%0APosts.update%20nextPost._id%2C%20%24set%3A%20position%3A%20nextPost.position%20-%201) and see that the output will be the same.

Answer (score 3):

In CoffeeScript you can omit the parenthesis in all cases:

```
prevPost = Posts.findOne position: @position - 1

@Posts = new Meteor.Collection "posts"
```

I think it is a matter of style if you drop the parenthesis.

If you are in the "mood" of omitting parenthesis, be aware that you cannot omit them when there is no argument.

This will assign foo to bar

```
bar = foo
```

This will assign the returned value of the function foo to bar:

```
bar = foo()
```